# Throughput in sliding window protocol

Tags: computer-networks

Can anyone help me with this test question ? I am not really expert on this.

Assume $1000$BASE-LX network. Communication is using sliding window protocol with $15$ frames, each frame with $1000$ data bytes. The trace is $100$ km long and there is $3$ routers between sender and receiver. Calculate maximum possible data throughput.

So far, i calculated propagation time, which is $500$ us, ($\frac{d}{v}$; $v=2*10E8$, $d=10E4$).  Now i am wondering how to continue. I presume, that this network has $1$Gbit/s, so one packet will have transmission time $8$ us. There is nothing about ACK frame in the question, so can I ignore it ? Thanks for help, i am really lame beginner in the networking.

Comment: I am a layman to networking. But you should mention what ACK is ? what is the unit "us" ?

Comment: @sasha ACK(nowledgement) is basically a frame sent by the receiver of a frame that lets the sender know that that frame has been received succesfully

Comment: Are you sure the description is full? LX has range 10km (or I misunderstood the part about trace).